# How do I use my Jquery plugin in the Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

My company introduced a way to use social share buttons without providing tracking data to the social sites on page load: [jquery.socialshareprivacy](http://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/).

How can I use it in a Rails 3.2 asset pipeline?

Comment: +1 for adding to the knowledge base on SO, but please add self-answer questions only once `:)`.

Comment: And: I'm not very pleased with the editing of Goerge!
My hint is not about just any jQuery plugin but for the specific one mentioned in the orgiginal title.
Second, it implies that I'm an employee of the author of the plugin, what I'm not!

Comment: The reason you are notified about edits on your posts is that you are free to correct the correction if you wish. You can rollback if you feel the whole edit was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin consists of a JS file and a directory with css and images.

Rails 3.2 comes with jQuery 1.9.x and the `jquery.socialshareprivacy.js` uses functions, removed in 1.9 (`.live $.browser`), so you have to patch it (get patch at [first gist](https://gist.github.com/mameier/5099718)) Using the asset pipeline requires to use different file paths for the images, so I patched the CSS (see [second gist](https://gist.github.com/mameier/5102433)) and turned it into an SCSS (append `.scss` to the filename).
I basically turned three `url()` into `image-url()`.

I put the JS in `vendor/assets/javascripts` and the whole CSS+images folder (socialshareprivacy) under `vendor/assets/stylesheets`

When I place the share buttons on a page (see [this documentation](http://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/)), I set the image urls in the options:

```
<div id="socialshareprivacy"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#socialshareprivacy').socialSharePrivacy({
            'css_path': '<%= asset_path 'socialshareprivacy/socialshareprivacy.css' %>',
            services: {
                facebook: {dummy_img: '<%= asset_path 'socialshareprivacy/images/dummy_facebook.png' %>'},
                twitter: {dummy_img: '<%= asset_path 'socialshareprivacy/images/dummy_twitter.png' %>'},
                gplus: {dummy_img: '<%= asset_path 'socialshareprivacy/images/dummy_gplus.png' %>'}
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you need it in several places, consider turning it into a partial.